# Email in loop sends the same file using Email class in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

Hey I'm using Codeigniter's Email helpers, and expiriencing a wierd issue. I have the following code :

```
        $path = mpdf_create_billing($html);
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('no-reply@foo.com');
        $this->email->to("foo@gmail.com");
        $this->email->subject('Invoice for  '.date('d/m/y'));
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->attach($path);
        if($this->email->send())
            echo "Email Sent Successfully to $email with the file $path<br>";
        else
            echo "Should be sending email to $email , but i didn't<br>";
```

Now this code is inside a foreach loop,twice in this case. `mpdf_create_billing` returns path to a PDF file. now this code echos 2 different file paths, but the email is the same and in both loop runs and both of the emails contain the same file, though the file paths are different.

Anyone knows how to resolve it? this is what outputs for me :

```
Email Sent Successfully to foo@foo.com with the file
   /path/to/pdf/Invoice_1368452801.82065190eec1c85eb.pdf

Email Sent Successfully to foo@foo.com with the file 
  /path/to/pdf/Invoice_1368452804.53475190eec482917.pdf
```

Could this be a problem with my SMTP server that send the emails? I tried it on 2 mail accounts, and same result.

Comment: Why don't you create `$path` outside of the loop?

Comment: @andrewsi It's a different path each run, as I want to send a different file, but the same one gets sent.

Comment: I'd say in that case, it's an issue with the `$html` variable - can you post the rest of the `for` loop code?

Comment: @andrewsi the rest are all calls to functions, it couldn't be related to the `$html` var, both of the paths are created and the actuall files are different and exist on in their path. and `$html` is just a string

Comment: So two different PDF files are being generated, but the mailer is sending out two emails, both including the first one? I guess the only thing I can suggest is that you try to explicitly unset the email, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you should clear $this->email?

From the CodeIgniter docs:

```
$this->email->clear()
```

> Initializes all the email variables to an empty state. This function
>   is intended for use if you run the email sending function in a loop,
>   permitting the data to be reset between cycles.

```
foreach ($list as $name => $address)
{
    $this->email->clear();

    $this->email->to($address);
    $this->email->from('your@example.com');
    $this->email->subject('Here is your info '.$name);
    $this->email->message('Hi '.$name.' Here is the info you requested.');
    $this->email->send();
}
```

> If you set the parameter to TRUE any attachments will be cleared as
>   well:

```
$this->email->clear(TRUE);
```

Looks to me this is what you are doing?

Link CI3: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Link CI2: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/email.html