# Codeigniter + Mailgun + recipient variables

Tags: email, smtp, codeigniter-3, mailgun

I would like to send email to many recipients using Codeigniter , Mailgun with SMTP.

My setup is

```
         $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
      $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

      $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
      $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.mailgun.org';
      $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
      $config['smtp_user'] = '[your Mailgun SMTP username]';
      $config['smtp_pass'] = '[your Mailgun SMTP password]';
      $config['smtp_timeout'] = '4';
      $config['crlf'] = '\n';
      $config['newline'] = '\r\n';

$arr = array(
 'firstEmail@email.com' => array(
      'id' => '3123213',
      ),
  'secondEmail@email.com' => array(
      'id' => '423423423',
   )   
);

$this->email->set_header('X-Mailgun-Recipient-Variables',json_encode($arr));
$this->email->from('myEmail@email.com');
$this->email->to('firstEmail@email.com,secondEmail@email.com');
$this->email->subject("Subject");
$message = 'Message';
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
```

Above is my setup. Emails are send but each recipient can see other recipients - and i suppose because i setup incorrectly the X-Mailgun-Recipient-Variables.

Instructions are here https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#batch-sending but i really dont know what i did wrong.

I will be appriciate for any help

Answer (score 1):

You are sending `to` multiple recipients and so yes they will see each other.

What you need to do is create an array with your emails and then do a foreach loop and send emails to only one `to` recipient at a time.

Try this:

```
$addresses = array('firstEmail@email.com','secondEmail@email.com');
foreach ($addresses as $to){
    $this->email->set_header('X-Mailgun-Recipient-Variables',json_encode($arr));
    $this->email->from('myEmail@email.com');
    $this->email->subject("Subject");
    $message = 'Message';
    $this->email->message($message);    
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->send();

    $this->email->clear();
}
```

I forgot about clear(). ([Email in loop sends the same file using Email class in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523879)) This is necessary to reset the variables.